# ios region monitoring does authorization have to be set to always

Tags: ios, location

When i am using Geo Region Monitoring on iOS, my entry and exit delegates are never fired unless I set the locationmanager authorization status to be always.

Even when the app is in the foreground the events do not occur.

As soon as I switch to Always, hey it all works.

Ive set my location manager up as follows

```
self.sharedLocationManager = [sbLocationManagerHelper sharedLocationManagerHelper];
self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOther;

if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
    || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
{
    [self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
} [self.sharedLocationManager.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Is there a way to make this work where the Location icon disapears when the app is backgrounded but the region monitoring still occurs, or even shows the region monitoring icon instead ?

I am using SDK 9 and targetting ios 8 +

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you have to use requestAlwaysAuthorization for GeoFencing to work.

However when you application is in the background, or not running, you should see the geofence icon (outlined location services icon) and not the full purple location services icon.

Are you calling startUpdatingLocation or startUpdatingHeading in your code? If so then you will see the full location services icon since your application is monitoring the users location. If you do not need their specific location make sure to call stopUpdatingLocation or stopUpdatingHeading.

Comment: Thanks I am calling startUpdatingLocation as it uses the current location to figure out what geo-fences it needs set up. Thanks for your answer makes sense now.